# urllib response.read() not working as expected

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I am currently trying to return the post response from urllib. The response is fine when i print it using response.read() it prints. However if i allocate this to a variable d and then print or return it. It is empty. How to fix this issue.

```
def update_cancel_job(self,userid,apiKey,secret,source,server,jobtids):
    rv = RequestValidation()
    hsh = rv.CreateAPISecret(str(userid), str(apiKey), str(secret)) 
    getVars ={'id':str(userid),'key':str(apiKey),'jobs':int(jobtids),'source':source,'hsh':hsh}
    url=server+"/api/outsource/job/cancel/?"
    data= urllib.urlencode(getVars)
    response_from_executor=urllib2.urlopen(url,data)
    #the below line prints fine
    print response_from_executor.read()
    print type(response_from_executor)
    #the below line however does not. It prints empty
    d = response_from_executor.read()
    print d
    #the reuturn is also empty
    return d
```

Comment: You can only read it once, like a stream. Try removing the first `print`.

Comment: try `response_from_executor.read().decode('utf-8')`

Comment: When you `print response_from_executor.read()`, the whole content of the document is read and displayed. When you then assign `d = response_from_executor.read()`, there is no more data to read. So, first do the assignment and then `print d`.

Comment: DYZ yes thats exactly what i wanted. Thank you :-)

Comment: If an answer helped you, please consider voting it up/accepting as answer.

Comment: I have but my reputation is not high enough i believe to make an impact.. Sorry :-/

Answer (score 0):

The server is sending you a stream of bytes; there's no way to "rewind"
that without issuing another request.

Answer (score 0):

now if you call update_Cancel_job() it will print the response yet return the response to whatever you call the function with. The key is saving the values in a variable first so you can work with them. Also if you need to access `d`outside of the function you can set it to `global`.

```
def update_cancel_job(self,userid,apiKey,secret,source,server,jobtids):
    rv = RequestValidation()
    hsh = rv.CreateAPISecret(str(userid), str(apiKey), str(secret)) 
    getVars ={'id':str(userid),'key':str(apiKey),'jobs':int(jobtids),'source':source,'hsh':hsh}
    url=server+"/api/outsource/job/cancel/?"
    data= urllib.urlencode(getVars)
    response_from_executor=urllib2.urlopen(url,data)
    d = response_from_executor.read()
    print type(d)
    print d
    return d
```